# LNK2019 & LNK1120 Unresolved Externals Probably an easy fix, but I'm having real trouble

Tags: lnk2019, unresolved-external

I've been getting these LNK2019s for a little while now and can't seem to find a way to get rid of them. I'm aware that there are a lot of threads on these errors already, but I've yet to find anything that's helped me so hoped someone might miss something glaringly obvious I may have missed.

I've not learnt very traditionally, so sorry if my code's a bit messy.

main:

```
#include "eventLoop.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool buttonA, buttonB, buttonC, buttonD, buttonE, buttonF, buttonG = false;
bool KeepProgramOpen = true;
time_t timer;
time_t oldtime;
time_t dtime;
time_t looptime;
int rate;
char Note;
bool FirstLoop = true;

eventLoop MainEventLoop;

int main()
{
    rate = 60;
    looptime = 1000 / rate;

    while(KeepProgramOpen==true)
    {

        time(&timer);
        dtime = timer-oldtime;

        if(dtime<looptime)
        {
            continue;
        }

        oldtime = timer;

        MainEventLoop.FindFinalNote(buttonA, buttonB, buttonC, buttonD, buttonE, buttonF, buttonG, FirstLoop);

        FirstLoop = false;

    //Closing stuff goes here
    }
}
```

eventLoop.h:

```
#pragma once

class eventLoop {

public:

    void FindFinalNote(bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool);

protected:

};
```

eventLoop.cpp:

```
#include "eventLoop.h"
#include "MidiOutput.h"
#include "FileIO.h"

MidiOutput MidiOutputX;

FileIO fileioX;

void eventLoop::FindFinalNote(bool A, bool B, bool C, bool D, bool E, bool F, bool G, bool firstloop)
{

    if(firstloop == true)
    {
        for (int loopindex=0; loopindex<10; loopindex++)
        {
        //  Note[loopindex] = Filecheck for notes
        }

        MidiOutputX.FindDevice(
            1,   /*int argc number of ports*/
            60,  /*char argv argument vector - strings pointed to, i don't really get it*/
        );
    }

    char Note[10];
    int KeyIndex = 0;
    FileIO::key CurrentKey;

    CurrentKey = fileioX.RetrieveKey(KeyIndex);

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        Note[x] = CurrentKey.Note[x];
    }

    //  There's a bunch of simple if statements here, nothing I need to bore you with
}
```

MidiOutput.h:

```
#pragma once

class MidiOutput {

public:

void FindDevice(int, char);
void PlayNote(unsigned char);
void EndNote();
void CloseDevice();

protected:

};
```

MidiOutput.cpp:

```
#include "MidiOutput.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <stdio.h>

union { unsigned long word; unsigned char data[4]; } message;
int midiport;
HMIDIOUT device;

void FindDevice(int argc, char** argv)
{

    if (argc < 2) {
        midiport = 0;
    } else {
        midiport = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    printf("Midi output port set to %d.\n", midiport);

    midiOutOpen(&device, midiport, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL);

    message.data[0] = 0x90; //command byte
    message.data[1] = 60; //middle C 
    message.data[2] = 0; //volume, 0-100
    message.data[3] = 0; //not used
}

void MidiOutput::PlayNote(unsigned char Note)
{
    message.data[1] = Note;
    message.data[2] = 100;
}

void MidiOutput::EndNote()
{
    message.data[2] = 0;
}

void MidiOutput::CloseDevice()
{
    midiOutReset(device);
    midiOutClose(device);
}
```

Exact Errors:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall MidiOutput::FindDevice(int,char)" (?FindDevice@MidiOutput@@QAEXHD@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall eventLoop::FindFinalNote(bool,bool,bool,bool,bool,bool,bool,bool)" (?FindFinalNote@eventLoop@@QAEX_N0000000@Z)  C:\Users\Hilly\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\GHX\GHX\eventLoop.obj  GHX
>
> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_midiOutOpen@20 referenced in function "void __cdecl FindDevice(int,char * *)" (?FindDevice@@YAXHPAPAD@Z)   C:\Users\Hilly\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\GHX\GHX\MidiOutput.obj GHX
>
> Error  3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_midiOutClose@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall MidiOutput::CloseDevice(void)" (?CloseDevice@MidiOutput@@QAEXXZ)    C:\Users\Hilly\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\GHX\GHX\MidiOutput.obj GHX
>
> Error  4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_midiOutReset@4 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall MidiOutput::CloseDevice(void)" (?CloseDevice@MidiOutput@@QAEXXZ)    C:\Users\Hilly\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\GHX\GHX\MidiOutput.obj GHX
>
> Error  5   error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Hilly\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\GHX\Debug\GHX.exe  GHX

Thanks in advance, and sorry about the wall of code, I'm not sure what's necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing symbols, `midiOutOpen`, `midiOutClose` etc. are defined in the DLL `Winmm.dll`. You will need to link to `Winmm.lib` by either specifying it as an input to the link command or by including this in your file:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")
```

You're also getting an error about `MidiOutput::FindDevice`. You will need to fix up the signatures so that the `.h` file and `.cpp` match, and qualify the function definition in the `.cpp` file with the class name (`MidiOutput::`).

Comment: I have tried qualifying the function that way, but it brings up another error, I'll try the rest now and see how it goes, cheers. - EDIT Yeah, it's caused another error, but my LNKs are sorted, thanks.